# What is the origin of the expression “failed state”?

Tags: etymology

I am trying to find the etymology of  ***[failed state](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/failed-state)***.  The expression appears to be from the '90s. Who coined it and why?

> a nation in which the government has lost political authority and control and is unable to fulfill the basic responsibilities of a sovereign state. (Dictionary.com)

Comment: I tried to Ngram this, but did not succeed in eliminating other meanings ... "failed state banks", or "the machine is in a failed state"

Comment: Your question should include the results of your search.

Answer (score 2):

According to the following article from [The Gurdian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/jun/28/failed-states-western-myth-us-interests) the expression  is from 1992:

> - ***The failed state was invented in late 1992 by Gerald Helman and Steven Ratner, two US state department employees, in an article in – you guessed it – Foreign Policy, suggestively entitled Saving failed states.***
> - ***With the end of the cold war, they argued, "a disturbing new phenomenon is emerging: the failed nation state,***  utterly incapable of sustaining itself as a member of the international community". And with that, the beast was born.

Also, from [The Fragility of the 'Failed State' Paradigm: A Different International Law ...](https://books.google.it/books?id=5Q5-fhdM258C&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=failed%20state%20origin&source=bl&ots=igy_WMENE4&sig=mI7g74G-cuq9c2BHgf-e74HnRdo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjckcqO9KnWAhUKvBQKHe_FCvAQ6AEIXTAP#v=onepage&q=failed%20state%20origin&f=false):

> - As noted above, while scholars have identified a growing number of countries as lacking effective governments ***and the "failed state" concept has become more popular since 1992***.....

Comment: Google scholar has a [1991 example usage](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22failed+state%22+political&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&as_ylo=1990&as_yhi=1991)  "Hence Cyprus, though a failed state. remained the only "life raft to the Greek Cypriots." - maybe multiple people can claim to have "invented" it.

Comment: I haven't looked myself, but I'd be very surprised if it originated in 1992 (or the '90s for that matter). But a quick search of the Wiki for the term has sources from the 2000s ...hmm intriguing.

Comment: From [*The Struggles for Poland*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fate+of+a+%27failed%27+nation-state%22) by Neal Ascherson, published 1987... *Europe now entered a period of huge wars between empires and of internal class struggle, in which the fate of a **'failed' nation-state** seemed steadily less relevant.* I'd say it's just a natural collocation, hardly something that merits looking for an "origin". But at least that earlier usage put scare quotes around the word ***'failed'***, suggesting that the writer hadn't *often* encountered it before, if at all.

Comment: ...here's another from 1913... [*It had scarcely weathered the panic when it found itself **a creditor of a failing State.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22creditor+of+a+failing+state%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers After the fall of Soviet Communism and the breakup of USSR and the Warsaw Pact, symbolized for an entire generation of Westerners by the fall of the Berlin Wall, *failed* became a very common collocation with anything related to Soviet Communism. Until then, Americans were trying to win. After that, we had won, and were left to deal with the aftermath of the "failed communist experiment". The usage became idiomatic and widespread throughout American government.  Cont ...

Comment: See here, p3, column 2, CJC Colin Powell, 1992. [NATIONAL MILITARY STRATEGY OF THE UNITED STATES](http://history.defense.gov/Portals/70/Documents/nms/nms1992.pdf?ver=2014-06-25-123420-723) . *Failed* became a euphemism for "on the losing side of the cold war'. In this sense, it is carries more water than just a natural collocation.

Comment: @Phil Sweet: I'd say the entire *concept* of "failed states" had little relevance to international political debate until well after WW2, simply because back then any such territories were simply hoovered up by powerful and well-organised imperialist nations. But most of what we might now think of as failed/failing states were never really "nations" in the first place (and I'd certainly say that applies to what we used to know as the USSR). The possibility of joining the two words ***failed state*** was always there- it's just that there was no *use* for it earlier.